# Meaning of $a1=flag and $a2=mode registers in MIPS

Tags: file, mips, cpu-registers

I don't understand what registers $a1 and $a2 are doing. In this book http://spimsimulator.sourceforge.net/HP_AppA.pdf there is no description what 1 or 0 in $a1 or $a2 should mean. There is only:
$a0 = filename (string), $a1 =
flags, $a2 = mode.
Which flags and what mode? There is no explanation.
For example in this code:

```
#write on file
#open
li $v0, 13      # system call for open file
la $a0, fout    # load address of output file
li $a1, 1       # Open for reading
li $a2, 0       
syscall         # open a file (file descriptor returned in $v0)
move $s6, $v0   # save the file descriptor 

#write
li $v0, 15      # system call for write to file
move $a0, $s6   # file descriptor 
la $a1, buffer  # address of buffer which to write
li $a2, 30      # buffer length
syscall         # write to file

#close
li $v0, 16      # system call for close file
move $a0, $s6   # file descriptor to close
syscall         # close file
```

Comment: I have also to use li $a1, 0x41 and li $a2, 0x1FF for writing to not existing file but I dont understand where to find all this flagst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is documented anywhere for SPIM (other than in the source code), but for MARS the following should be true:

```
flags: 0 = read-only
       1 = write-only with create
       9 = write-only with create and append

mode: Ignored.
```

**Edit:** I checked [SPIM's source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/spimsimulator/code/HEAD/tree/CPU/syscall.c), and it appears to just pass `$a1` and `$a2` on as `flags` and `mode` to [`open`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open).